# pdsh issues while connecting to another host machine

Tags: ssh, connection, host

I have been working around to find a solution of different issues while connecting to a another host through `pdsh` command. I have encountered following issues:

> - Error 1: `/etc/genders` genders file parse error
> - Error 2: `hostname`: connect: Connection refused
> - Error 3: no remote hosts specified

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to these issues:

- Check your host name given in `/etc/genders` which must exist in
  `/etc/hosts` for `hostname` resolution
- `pdsh` use `rsh` and not `ssh`. Therefore, add connection type in your `bashrc` file:

`export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh`